# Mysql Database Migration Error in Laravel

Tags: mysql, database, eloquent, database-migration, laravel-7

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreatePostsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {

            $table->bogIncrements('id');

            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');

            $table->string('caption');

            $table->string('image');

            $table->timestamps();

            $table->index('user_id');

        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()

    {

        Schema::dropIfExists('posts');

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$table->bogIncrements('id');` typo in here.